# Copy words with given letter from file to new file

Tags: c, file, char

I'm trying to copy words from one file to another, but the words must begin with the given letter. It's working but doesn't copy every word that matches.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *f = fopen("words.txt", "r");
    FILE *f2 = fopen("words_copy.txt", "a+");
    char usr;
    printf("enter letter: ");
    scanf("%c", &usr);
    char buffer[255];
    char ch, ch2;
    while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
        ch2 = fgetc(f);
        if (ch2 == usr && ch == '\n') {
            fputc(ch2, f2);
            fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), f);
            fputs(buffer, f2);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Words.txt** contains:

```
adorable aesthetic  alluring angelic appealing arresting attractive
blooming charismatic charming cherubic chocolate-box classy contagious
cute dazzling debonair decorative delectable delicate distinguished
enchanting enticing eye-catching glamorous glossy good-looking
gorgeous infectious lovely lush magnetic magnificent majestic melting
mesmerizing noble picturesque poetic prepossessing shimmering striking
stunning winsome
```

every word is in next line,
when I'm running the program and giving the letter `m` **words_copy.txt** contains only:

```
magnificent melting
```

How to fix to copy every word with matching letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test in the loop is incorrect: you check the first letter after a newline and output the line if there is a match. With this logic:

- you cannot match the first word in the file
- you only match words starting with `usr`
- and the word following a match is ignored

Furthermore, you `ch` and `ch2` should be defined with type `int` to match `EOF` reliably, you should test for `fopen` failure and close the files after use.

You should use a simpler approach:

- read a word
- test if it contains the letter
- output the word if it matches

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char usr;
    char buffer[256];
    int ch = 0;
    size_t pos;

    FILE *f = fopen("words.txt", "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open words.txt: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *f2 = fopen("words_copy.txt", "a+");
    if (f2 == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open words_copy.txt: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        fclose(f);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("enter letter: ");
    if (scanf(" %c", &usr) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "missing input\n");
        fclose(f);
        fclose(f2);
        return 1;
    }
    while (ch != EOF) {
        pos = 0;
        /* read a word, stop at whitespace and end of file */
        while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF && !isspace(ch)) {
            if (pos + 1 < sizeof(buffer))
                buffer[pos++] = (char)ch;
        }
        buffer[pos] = '\0';
        /* test for a match */
        if (strchr(buffer, usr)) {
            /* output matching word */
            fprintf(f2, "%s\n", buffer);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    fclose(f2);
    return 0;
}
```